# Moving Models from One collection to another [BackboneJS]

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Imagine I need to create a Single page application like Gmail, using BackboneJS.
Whenever a mail item is tagged with new labels/ removed the existing labels, the mail item should appear in the appropriate list.

I assume every list of e-mails, like Inbox, Sent Items, some custom labels, can be designed as a Collection. Whenever a mail item is archived or tagged with additional labels or removed existing labels, the mail item shall be removed from one list and added appropriately to some other list.

Is this a right design approach?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to put the e-mail `model` in lots of different `collection`s (like `inbox` and `sent`). This is possible. But i would advice to give the e-mail `model` this data. Tell the e-mail `model` it has this and this label.

You will have a `collection` of e-mails; in this `collection` you can create functions to easily extract `inbox` and `sent` models.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. This is perfect design approach. This makes easy for you to manage events as follows :

```
var Inpox = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Email,
    ....
});


var SentItem = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Email,
    ....
});

emailApp.on("sent",function(){// When sent triggered from Email

//Do sent email specific task

    backboneEventObject.trigger("add");
});

backboneEventObject.on("add", function(){
    newSentItemCollection.trigger("add");// Trigger add on the sent Item Collection
});
```